# Eventbridge payload is null when triggering Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-event-bridge

Previously I had S3 bucket notifications set up and the payload I received was (I've removed the fields I didn't use)

```
{  
   "Records":[  
      {  
         "s3":{  
            "bucket":{  
               "name":"bucket-name",
            },
            "object":{  
               "key":"object-key",
            }
         },
      }
   ]
}
```

(Info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html)

I have since updated my stack to use Event Bridge notifications. The rule is associated with my Lambda which is triggered when I drop a file in my S3 bucket.

I now get the following

```
{
  Records: []
}
```

I am wondering whether I need to add a template to my Event Bridge to send the bucket name and event.

Comment: It is really hard to suggest without knowing what are you using for the infrastructure. Is it terraform or SAM?